# Create Azure User via Graph with immutableID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to create an Azure user via Graph and we are federated so an immutableID is required. I understand how to do this but my question is... how do I generate an immutableID that I can send to graph when creating the user? Folks say it needs to be base64 encoded from the objects GUID but I don't have an object GUID until after the user is created so I have a chicken/egg scenario here.

I tried using a UPN in the immutableID field but it did not accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To set the **`immutableID`** to an Azure AD User, first you have to create user by using below query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Content-type: application/json

{
"accountEnabled": true,
"displayName": "Rukmini",
"mailNickname": "ruktest",
"userPrincipalName": "ruktest@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
"passwordProfile": {
"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
"password": "xxxx"
}
}
```

**The user got created successfully like below:**

[image]

The **`immutableID`** is the base64 encoded string of the `ObjectGUID` of the user.

To generate the **`immutableID`**, use the below PowerShell script:

```
$objectGuid = "ObjectIDOftheUser" 
$Bytes = [System.Guid]::Parse($objectGuid).ToByteArray()
$ImmutableId = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
$ImmutableId
```

[image]

**To set the **`immutableID`** to an Azure AD User**, use the below query:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserObjectID

Content-type: application/json
{
"onPremisesImmutableId": "ImmutableID"
}
```

[image]

The **`onPremisesImmutableId`** assigned to the User successfully like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ObjectID?$select=displayName,onPremisesImmutableId
```

[image]